UFW not logging [UFW BLOCK] events when default is to allow incoming connections
I'm trying to get a message logged to /var/log/ufw.log when blocking packets. It's all working very well, until I change the default behaviour for incoming connections.
I use ufw default allow incoming to allow all incoming connections by default.
Then, I add ufw reject from <my-ip>. However, nothing is logged.
I also tried using ufw deny from <my-ip>. Same issue.
The file /etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf is correctly configured. I've also tried changing the log level with ufw logging <level> with low, medium and full only to find that BLOCK messages are not logged. Every other message is correctly logged though (ALLOW and AUDIT).
Please help.

The basic defaault for ufw is to deny all incoming and allow all outgoing, it may be better for you to install gufw, that is a the GUI for UFW, and please edit your question, add version of Ubuntu.

I'm having the same issue on Debian 12. I have double and triple checked everything I know to check. No matter what logging level I set (ufw logging full), I get no logs at all. 20-ufw.conf seems to be set correctly, but /var/log/ufw.log is blank. Permissions match other files in the log directory. Nothing in syslog, kernlog, or journal, either.

Same problem here
